# How to run the dependabot cli in local or in github action to Scan an image URL and provide suggestions

Tags: github, github-actions

How to run the dependabot cli or any other tool in local or in github actions to Scan an docker image URL and provide suggestions with vulnerable free image tags.

I tried using skopeo and dependabot but didnt work as expected..

Comment: Looks like the scripts here are broken: https://github.com/dependabot/dependabot-script :'(